# Java return a value from a method using nested if else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a method that returns something depending on the if conditions. But when I am using the below code, it doesn't recognize my return statement and says to change the method declaration to void. Can you please help optimizing the code.

```
if(myList == null){
    return abc;
} else {
    for(myList myListItem : myList){            
        if(myList.getId() != null){
          if(TEST1.equals(myListItem.getId())){
            return abc;
          } else if(TEST2.equals(myListItem.getId())){
            return xyz;
          } else if(TEST3.equals(myListItem.getId())){
            return pqr;
        }
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: What return value do you expect if the list referred to by `myList` is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(myList == null){
    smth = abc;
} else {
    for(myList myListItem : myList){            
        if(myList.getId() != null){
          if(TEST1.equals(myListItem.getId())){
            smth = abc;
          } else if(TEST2.equals(myListItem.getId())){
            smth = xyz;
          } else if(TEST3.equals(myListItem.getId())){
            smth = pqr;
        }
    }  
 }
   return smth;
    }
```

Try this it will work for your function with different conditions

Comment: Be careful with this.  Its return value is based on the LAST value in the loop whose id matches TEST1, TEST2 or TEST3; whereas the return value of your original code (if it were made to compile) would be based on the FIRST such value in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For your else you are not returning anything... return something there or return something outside your if:

```
          else {
                for(myList myListItem : myList){            
                    if(myList.getId() != null){
                        if(TEST1.equals(myListItem.getId())){
                            return abc;
                        } else if(TEST2.equals(myListItem.getId())){
                            return xyz;
                        } else if(TEST3.equals(myListItem.getId())){
                            return pqr;
                        }
                    }  
                }
           **return something;**//<--here
           }
//or return here
return something;//<-- OR HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is simply telling you that there are paths within your code that would **not** see a return statement!

Your very first if in the for-block does **not** have an else; thus there is no return statement when that thing is null! And then - what happens if the for loop doesn't loop at all?!

In other words: believe your compiler. When it tells you, that your method "should be void", then it means: there is at least one path left that doesn't return a value. It won't stop complaining until you fixed all of those paths!

Finally: you might want to read about the **single layer of abstraction** principle. You see - you created code that is so hard to read that you didn't see that obvious problem. So you could step back now and learn *how to write **readable** code* ...

Answer (score -1):

```
if (myList != null) {
  for() {}
}
return abc;
```

Comment: two possibilities one is return outside if or add a return to else

Comment: At least, please add some explanation to your code. As it is, it doesn't even compile.